# How can I run a vb.net file using other tools not just running on visual studio?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, build

I create a window application using visual studio vb.net which including some textboxes and a button. But my boss wants me to create an executable file which can be run using other tools not just visual studio.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You already did it.

Look in your "My Documents" folder for the "Visual Studio 20xx" folder, and then "Projects", "<Your Project Name>", "<Your Project Name again>", "bin", and finally "Debug".  You'll have an .exe file there that will run without visual studio (it does still require .Net, though).

More than that, you should open visual studio and look under Project for Configuration Options.  Here you should be able to set it to build for Release, rather than Debug.

Comment: One thing to add to that. If you only want it to be run via other utilities or the command line, check out the CONSOLE APPLICATION project type (as opposed to the WinForms, or WPF project types). Console apps, don't show windows, they write output to the command line console, just like the DIR command does, for instance

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a windows executable project (Windows Forms, WPF, ETC) with Visual Studio every time you build the project an exe file is created that you could distribute to any machine running the .NET runtime.

You have this question tagged as ASP.NET, which is a server side setup.  If this is what you are doing currently, you will want to create a new project as a Windows Application and build it that way.

Comment: So, to extend what he said. If you have it constructed as a Windows Executable project, all you have to do is build the project and track down where it is placing the .exe file it created. Then, any computer containing the .Net runtime files (basically any computer that gets regular Windows Updates) and pass them that file. They'll be able to run it straight from the exe